What does a caret and an equal sign (^=) do in Python?
I was looking at the solution to a Python problem, and in it was
int ^= num

I don't understand what it means.
When I searched for it, I got a bunch of posts explaining what the caret sign does on its own, but I'm trying to figure out what ^= means.

This question is similar to: ^=, -= and += symbols in Python. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
